# Handle [] in __str__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):  
         self.var_a = []
         self.var_b = []
```

Is there a way I can define `__str__` on `A` such that I can pass an index in this fashion:

```
instance_a = A()    
# do stuff with instance_a causing var_a and var_b to populate
print( instance_a[idx] )
```

and get `__str__` to utilise the index and return something like:

```
return "var_a is " + str(var_a[idx]) + ", var_b is" + str(var_b[idx])
```

Comment: Which part of that involves `__str__`? It doesn't take any arguments, per the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), but if you want the syntax `instance_a[idx]` to work you need `__getitem__`, not `__str__`. It's the *result* of that method call you're then passing to `str`, and it's unclear what you expect that to be.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) it would be cleaner in calling code to have the logic of assembling the string happen without specifically having to call a method on the class, 2) I wanted __getitem__ to remain returning the native types of the underlying elements in a tuple, rather than cast to a string. But thinking about your comments, __str__ probably is not the route to go anyway.

Comment: Just make a regular method `def stringify(self, index):` or something. But you don't have control over passing extra arguments to `__str__`.

Answer (score 3):

To format strings with parameters, use `__format__`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):  
         self.var_a = []
         self.var_b = []

    def __format__(self, idx):
        idx = int(idx)
        return "var_a is {}, var_b is {}".format(self.var_a[idx], self.var_b[idx])
```

Example:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.var_a=[4,5,6]
>>> a.var_b=[1,2,3]
>>> '{:1}'.format(a)
'var_a is 5, var_b is 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `__getitem__`, not `__str__`.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_a = []
        self.var_b = []

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return "var_a is " + str(self.var_a[idx]) + ", var_b is" + str(self.var_b[idx])


>>> a = A()
>>> a.var_a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.var_b = [4,5,6]
>>> print(a[2])
var_a is 3, var_b is6
```